# How to add FB audience network to monetize a facebook canvas app?

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-canvas, facebook-audience-network

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/ describes ads for android and iOS apps but doesn't talk about FB Canvas apps.

Is it possible to add FB audience network to a FB canvas app? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Audience network only supports iOS and Android at the moment. You cannot use it for canvas apps right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the list od the Facebook authorized app providers here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/adproviders
But I don't know how they perform.

Comment: This should probably be a comment.